# One of my child Div's refuses to be centered with text-align:Center

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I'm having a strange issue, I simply want to vertically and horizontally center my parent div while maintaining a left align child div (text,divs, etc.). 
**This is what I want:** [image: The results that I want]

But when I tried to add a **text-align:center** to the parent container this is what I got instead:

[image: The problem with text-align]

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/wbg6woqv/1/) without the text-align:center, I've been working on this for too many days, and no matter what I do I can't keep the text left aligned when they they center, and the child div (numbers) refuse to center. **Can someone please show me how to correctly vertically and horizontally center my Parent container while maintaining the left alignment?**

Here's my CSS:

```
.bigwrapper {display:table; height:100vh;  width: 100%; }

.listwrapper {background:#fff; vertical-align:middle!important;display:table-cell; }

.point {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.message {
    display: inline-block;
}
.title {
    color: black;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-right: 60px; font-size:19px;
}
.info {
    color: #999;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-right: 60px; margin-top:5px;
}

.number {
      font: 36px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;vertical-align:bottom;
    margin-right: 10px; margin-top:5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.number {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}




.listwrapper p {
  font-size: 13px !important; font-weight:bold; color:#333;
}


.listwrapper .form-control {min-width:100%!important; height:35px; font-size:13px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; display:inline-block;}
.listwrapper .btn {min-width:100%!important; display:block; height:35px; font-size:12px; margin-top:10px;}

.listwrapper .btn {background:#333 !important; color:#fff !important; font-weight:bold;}

.listwrapper .btn:hover {background:#000 !important; color:#fff !important;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bigwrapper">
    <div class="listwrapper">

        <div class="point">
            <div class="number">1</div>
            <div class="message">
                <div class="title">Upload your media and get discovered</div>
                <div class="info">Share, find, buy, or sell any type of content with the help of filters</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="point">
            <div class="number">2</div>
            <div class="message">
                <div class="title">Represent your city everytime you post</div>
                <div class="info">Raise local awareness with tags linked to content in your area</div>
            </div>
        </div>


         <div class="point">
            <div class="number">3</div>
            <div class="message">
                <div class="title">Make real connections with users nearby</div>
           <div class="info">Connect with neighbors, friends, fans, and rising stars in your city</div>
            </div>
        </div>

     <div class="point">
            <div class="number">4</div>
            <div class="message">
                <div class="title">Get started by typing your email address</div>

                     <div class="guestlist">
                <form class="guestlist-form form-inline" action="signup" method="post">
           <input name="emailaddress" class="form-control input-lg" id="enterfield" type="email" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
           <input class="button btn-lg btn" title="Enter Email" name="submit" type="submit" autofocus="autofocus" value="Sign up!"> 
                </form>
              <div id="error-message"></div><span class="spam">Don't worry we won't spam</span>
             </div> 

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why define `.number` twice in the css? For the rest: You main div just is wide. It is centered in the relative space available. Perhaps use right instead of center

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen can you please elaborate? My main div:bigwrapper is set to 100vw isn't that the entire available width of the window? How will you center this vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to `.bigwrapper` to center the element that holds all of that content `.listwrapper`.

`align-items: center` will vertically center `.listwrapper` inside of `.bigwrapper` and `justify-content: center;` will horizontally align it.

```css
.point {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.message {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  color: black;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.info {
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.number {
  font: 36px Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.number {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.listwrapper p {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}

.listwrapper .form-control {
  min-width: 100%!important;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.listwrapper .btn {
  min-width: 100%!important;
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.listwrapper .btn {
  background: #333 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.listwrapper .btn:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.bigwrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.listwrapper {
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bigwrapper">
    <div class="listwrapper">

      <div class="point">
        <div class="number">1</div>
        <div class="message">
          <div class="title">Upload your media and get discovered</div>
          <div class="info">Share, find, buy, or sell any type of content with the help of filters</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="number">2</div>
        <div class="message">
          <div class="title">Represent your city everytime you post</div>
          <div class="info">Raise local awareness with tags linked to content in your area</div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="point">
        <div class="number">3</div>
        <div class="message">
          <div class="title">Make real connections with users nearby</div>
          <div class="info">Connect with neighbors, friends, fans, and rising stars in your city</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="point">
        <div class="number">4</div>
        <div class="message">
          <div class="title">Get started by typing your email address</div>

          <div class="guestlist">
            <form class="guestlist-form form-inline" action="signup" method="post">
              <input name="emailaddress" class="form-control input-lg" id="enterfield" type="email" title="Enter Email Address" class="guestlistfield" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
              <input class="button btn-lg btn" title="Enter Email" name="submit" type="submit" autofocus="autofocus" value="Sign up!">
            </form>
            <div id="error-message"></div><span class="spam">Don't worry we won't spam</span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm still new to display flex, so can you help me understand the logic behind it? How does align-items and justify-content work together or why o you need both?

Comment: @ChosenJuan did you read the text I put in the answer? *"align-items: center will vertically center .listwrapper inside of .bigwrapper and justify-content: center; will horizontally align it."* You only need `justify-content` to center horizontally, but you may want to use `align-items` to center vertically, too. It's up to you, you can take `align-items` out and see if you need it. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to do this without flexbox? How do I target older browsers? Do I need a fallback for flexbox, align-items, and justify-content?

Comment: @ChosenJuan flexbox has 98% global browser support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox updaed my answer with the prefixed flex properties. You can use autoprefixer for that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the links and for your great answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can set child div-s to be `display:inline-block;` and then for it parent `width:100%;text-align:center;`

But to center them vertically You need to use jQuery or redesign Your layout and set left element and right element to be `display:inline-block` in one container with `text-align:center;` and then use vertical-align property for left and right element.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the css for the "big-wrapper" class to:

```
.bigwrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: table;
}
```